# Converting Circular formulae to Independent functions

Tags: recurrence-relations, closed-form, recursive-algorithms, data-analysis, analytic-functions

I have a set of equations which I'm trying to transform from a recursive relationship to a more absolute/relative notation. Ideally this is to transform row-based logic into a set-based one for SQL.

I currently have the following equations where $A_n$, $I_n$, and $S_n$ are given for all $_n$ and $\alpha_0 = 0$:
$$\begin{align}
\alpha_n &= \omega_{n-1} \\
\beta_n &= \alpha_n + I_n - S_n \\
\delta_n &= A_n \times \beta_n \\
\omega_n &= \beta_n - \delta_n
\end{align}$$

Because of the dependency between $\alpha_n$ and the previous $\omega_{n-1}$, it only allows for a row-based calculation which considerably slows down the SQL performance.

I'm looking for a transformation of the above equations to more of a set-based approach, and I've gotten to something along the lines of the following (but can't implement due to the circular dependencies):
$$\begin{align}
\alpha_n &= \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\Delta_k \\
\beta_n &= \alpha_n + I_n - S_n \\
\delta_n &= A_n \times \beta_n \\
\Delta_n &= I_n - S_n - \delta_n \\
\omega_n &= \sum_{k=0}^n\Delta_k
\end{align}$$

I just need an **independent** function that can support the other derived values. I think closed-form? Much like how the $n^{th}$ Fibonacci number can be represented with $$F_n=\frac{(1+5^{1/2})^n -(1-5^{1/2})^n}{2^n\sqrt5}$$

First time posting here, I welcome all corrections, Thanks!

---

### Edit:

I broke out the [recurrence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving_first-order_non-homogeneous_recurrence_relations_with_variable_coefficients) provided by @AlexRavsky in Excel using:
$$\begin{align}
f_n &= 1 - A_n \\
g_n &= f_n (I_n - S_n) \\
h_n &= \prod_{k=0}^{n-1} f_k \text{, where } h_0 = 1 \\
i_n &= \sum_{m=0}^{n-1}\frac{g_m}{h_m} \text{, where } i_0 = 0 \\
\chi_n &= h_n (X_0 + i_n)
\end{align}$$

I couldn't figure out what $X_0$ is by changing what $\chi$ represents as $\chi \in \{\alpha, \beta, \delta, \omega\}$ from my original set of equations in Excel. I hope I didn't mess up on the equations above $(f_n, g_n, h_n, i_n, \text{or } \chi_n)$, still need a bit more information to get this working as they don't match with my expected values.

Comment: Do these equations come from SIR model ?

Comment: No, this is coming from the Finance world dealing with Asset Depreciation. I'm an Engineer trying to speed up business calculations.

Comment: Are $I_n,S_n,A_n $ known for all $n$.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah Yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As hamam_Abdallah [showed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3733330/converting-circular-formulae-to-independent-functions/3733352#3733352), $\alpha_{n+1}=f_n \alpha_n+g_n$,
where $f_n=1-A_n$ and $g_n=(1-A_n)(I_n-S_n)$. This is a [first-order non-homogeneous recurrence relation with variable coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving_first-order_non-homogeneous_recurrence_relations_with_variable_coefficients). So, provided all $A_n$ are distinct from $1$, its solution (for $n\ge 1$) is

$$\alpha_n=\left(\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} f_k\right)\left(\alpha_0+\sum_{m=0}^{n-1}\frac{g_m}{\prod_{k=0}^m f_k}  \right).$$

I guess that the formulae for $\beta_n$, $\delta_n$, and $\omega_n$ are similar, but for some special cases of $\{A_n\}$,  $\{I_n\}$, and $\{S_n\}$ they can be more simple.

Comment: This is awesome... what is $f_k$, and $g_m$ in this case? I need to learn how to translate this into SQL to test, lol

Comment: @SunnyPatel $f_n$ and $g_n$ are defined at the beginning of the answer.

Comment: Give this man the bounty.

Comment: Sure; but just working on the details. @AlexRavsky, The $A_0$ in the main equation is not the same as $A_n$ that I'm working with, and if $A_0 = \frac{a_0}{\prod_{k=0}^{0-1} f_k} = \alpha_0$, but not sure what $\alpha$ is referring to here. I promise I'm not dense; just solving recurrence relations is new to me. Thanks

Comment: Would $a_0 = g_0 = A_0$ in this case?

Comment: @AlexRavsky, I've updated my question with more details on my progress since I'm still stuck.

Comment: @SunnyPatel Oops, I copied $A_0$ from Wikipedia’s formula instead of adapting it to your notation, sorry. I fixed this issue. Sorry for the delay.

Comment: It was much easier to code for $\omega_n$ from your adaptation. In the end, $f_n$ and $g_n$ are defined accurately, but I used $\omega_n = (\prod_{k=0}^{n} f_k)(\alpha_0+\sum_{m=0}^{n}\frac{g_m}{\prod_{k=0}^m f_k})$. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

$$\alpha_{n+1}=\omega_n=$$
$$\beta_n-\delta_n=\beta_n(1-A_n)$$

$$=(\alpha_n+I_n-S_n)(1-A_n)$$

Comment: I'm trying to avoid direct references to the previous or next line with $n\pm1$.. aggregates are ok though.

Comment: Funny enough, I have had the last line on my whiteboard; but it brings be back to the same issue.